# Recursively create directory tree within existing subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a working directory with a large number of subfolders (i.e 1190A, 1993A etc).

```
'/working/1190A'
'/working/1993A'
```

I would like to recursively create a certain directory tree within each subfolder. For example:

```
'/working/1190A/analysis/1'
'/working/1993A/analysis/1'
etc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To force the system create a directory tree without having to create each level of it, add `-p` to the `mkdir` command.

Hence, this could work:

```
for dir in list_of_folders
do
   mkdir -p $dir/your/directory/tree
   [ $? ] && echo "error on $dir" # if the dir could not be created, print error (thanks @hetepeperfan - see comments)
done
```

Note that the `list_of_folders` can be given like `/working/1190A /working/1993A`, but also generated with a `find` command. This is just a first version you'd better adapt to your specific requirements.

Comment: It might be wise to check exit status of mkdir, otherwise OP might get errors later in the process.

Comment: Thanks, @hetepeperfan, I added an `echo` in such case.

Comment: May be better to get list of folders through `find /working/ -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Comment: Yes, @Rohan, I see the point and I think it is a smart way. Anyway, as we do not have many specifications given by the OP I prefer to add a *This is just a first version you'd better adapt to your specific requirements* comment at the end. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This is one liner as

```
cd /working
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec  mkdir -p '{}'/analysis/1 \;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourDirList=/working/*
for f in $yourDirList
do
    if [ -d $f ]
        mkdir -p $f/analysis/1
    fi
done
```